# Keep last activity visible after activityOpenExitAnimation

Tags: android, animation

In Android, I'm doing an animation that way:

```
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_from_left_to_zero</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_from_zero_to_tab_right</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_from_tab_right_to_zero</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_from_zero_to_left</item>
```

So, I'm using the 4 animations. Everything animates fine, but once animated, I can't see my last activity anymore behind my new activity, even if the new activity is transparent and doesn't take all the room in the screen.

I can add `windowIsFloating` but this actually just takes a screenshot of the last activity and prevent 2 of the 4 animations from being launched.

Can I always keep last activity visible behind AND have an animation on it?